# Call mysql procedure without defining parameter in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, stored-procedures

How to call a mysql procedure with parameter in vb.net without defining ther parameters in vb.net.

Here is my code:

MYSQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `usp_totalprice`(IN `id` INT) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER select count(*) as total from tbl_extra where foodID = id
```

VB.NET

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("usp_totalprice", "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=hrmsbf;")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@id", 1))
    da.Fill(ds)
    MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0))
```

I've got this error:

> Incorrect number of arguments for PROCEDURE hrmsbf.usp_totalprice;
>   expected 1, got 0.

I tried this 
`"Dim da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("usp_totalprice(@id)", "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=hrmsbf;")"` and this is working but that's not what i want.

Comment: da.SelectCommand.Parameters("@id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input specify direction

Comment: thanks @MukeshKalgude but how to assign id's value?

i tried this one "da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@id", 1)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input" but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

try to this way

```
Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter("usp_totalprice", "server=localhost; user id=root; password=; database=hrmsbf;")
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlParameter("@id", 1))
da.SelectCommand.Parameters("@id").Direction = ParameterDirection.Input
    da.Fill(ds)
    MsgBox(ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(0))
```